# Как реализовать единственное соединение с помощью сокета на андроиде?

Tags: java, android, сокет, client

Здравствуйте. У меня есть самописный сервер, и есть недописанное приложение под андроид. Мне нужно реализовать соединение с сервером (так как я еще на стадии обучения, я предпочитаю обычный сокет, но если есть варианты лучше, я прислушаюсь к ним), соединение должно быть единственное, так как на сервере создается сессия на каждое входящее подключение.

Вопрос: как лучше это сделать? Организовать сокет на сервисе или реализовать на треде?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, есть клиент, есть сервер, клиент подключается к серверу, создается подключение. Все. В чем вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос в том, куда засунуть сокет. Использовать AsynTask или обычный Thread, нужен ли слушателю отдельный поток, нужен ли отдельный поток для отправки данных серверу, как это всё будет выглядеть при переходе между активити?

Comment: Сервер работает в цикле while(true) и каждое подключение обрабатывает отдельно. Клиент в андройде вроде запускается в отдельном потоке. Точнее уже не скажу, не работал с андройдом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Сокет надо сажать в `IntentService`
2. Еще надо принять специальные меры, чтобы коннект не пропадал при засыпании устройства - смотрите в сторону `WakeLock`

Ну и самое главное: организация соединения на сокетах для мобильного устройства не является хорошей практикой.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а в какую сторону смотреть при реализации соединения с сервером?

Comment: Стандартная практика на стороне клиента http, на которые сервер отвечает в духе RESTful web services